# Is "skunkworks" used in British English?

Tags: british-english

Is the originally American English "[skunkworks](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/skunk-works)" also used in BE? And if it is, is it still regarded as being an Americanism, or has it been assimilated into BE?

Comment: Do UK-connected dictionaries like Cambridge, Oxford Languages (a) list this, (b) add a regional (or other) caveat, Swenglish?

Comment: I've never heard the word. I'm English, aged 56.

Comment: Edwin Ashworth@: Cambridge Dictionary and The Oxford English Dictionary both list 'skunkworks' (Cambridge: "skunk works") and with no caveats.

Comment: The word retains very strong associations with America. Although the OED has "no caveats", **all** the examples are from America or make strong reference to the skunkworks being in America. I would not, in dialogue, have "skunkworks" said by a BE speaker unless it were ironic and directed towards an American.

Comment: Very easy to find: https://www.techtarget.com/searchcio/definition/skunkworks A skunkworks project, also known as Skunk Works, is an innovative undertaking, involving a small group of people, that is outside the normal research and development (R&D) channels within an organization.

Skunk Works was the name given to a secret R&D team at Lockheed Aircraft Corp. tasked with quickly developing a jet fighter for the United States during World War II.

Comment: Thanks, Greybeard. Is there any BE word with the same ring to it as "skunkworks" that you could recommend?

Comment: Oh, I wish I had not posted my first comment. Ja prate inte svenska.

Comment: @Sweglish It depends on the context - you should give some: "The dirty-tricks department"; "The black-arts people"; "Special purposes R&D", the blackhats, / whitehats, etc.

Comment: Even in the US it's a technical term in engineering circles, so most people won't know it. But those in the UK familiar with that area may know it.